# notifications/indications -- use of IBluetoothGattCallback.Stub in latest motorola ble APIs

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, motorola-droid

in the older version of the motorola ble APIs, notifications/indications would be received through an implementation of an IBluetoothGattCallback.Stub....

in the more recent version of the APIs -- which introduced the new IBluetoothGattProfile.Stub class -- i'm not all that sure how to receive notifications/indications....  i've implemented an IBluetoothGattProfile.Stub, and do receive calls on the other methods as expected....  i assume the onValueChanged() method is where i would receive a callback when the underlying stack has received a notification/indication ???

using the setCharacteristicClientConf() method, i have enabled receipt of notifications/indications on the client side; and the appropriate BLE packet has made it over to the server side....  in general, the air-trace looks normal -- no different than what i see when connecting (say) with an iphone....

looking at log messages from the underlying bluetooth service, i see no activity there -- when in fact incoming notifications/indications are being transmitted over the air....

any insight on how to enable receipt of notifications/indications with the latest moto ble API would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: just figured out you have to call registerWatcher() on your BluetoothGattService object....  the method onValueChanged() is now being called correctly....

Comment: did you get this working with the Proximity Profile by any chance? having major headaches trying to adapt it.